# How to create a table in access and automatically fills it with information from a query?

Tags: database-design, ms-access, master-data-services

Is it possible if I create a table that will lookup for a value filtered from a query (consult), in this case is duplicated "Name"s from a Employees registring table and automaticly fills up that number of registers, then the only thing that I need to change is the values of other fields I made in this new automatic-table?

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. Do you want to create and populate some of the columns of the table before running the query and then use the query to update some other columns? I believe a good example would help very much in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds likes you would be best served by using another Query, not a Table.  In Access you can use a Query much like a Table, even use a saved Query as a source in another Query.  If you are careful you can create an Editable Query, in which changes you make to the Query results directly affect the Base Table.  It can be tricky to do so when you have more then one Table/Query involved, as it sounds like you do, but it is a possibility.

[You can read more about Editable Queries here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-data-in-a-query-6CA3EDFC-6D66-4D90-8219-C2B258D5BED7)